Interpretation + Information leads to infinite recursion
It looks like a bug, or am I using Interpretation incorrectly?
Any workaround?
Example
First, we give the following definition so that x[i] is formatted as Subscript[x,i], and remains to be x[i] itself when copying/pasting. This method is more flexible than MakeBoxes+MakeExpression.
ClearAll[x,f]

Format[x[i_]]:=
    Interpretation[Subscript[x,i],x[i]];

??x


Now everything is fine.
But if we define another function involving x, then infinite recursion occurs
f[i_]:=x[i]

??f


f//Information or "f"//Information does not help. This seems to be a bug of Information only. GeneralUtilities`PrintDefinitionsLocal, DownValues, Definition and FullDefinition work as expected.

It's worth pointing out this seems to be related to frontend. Information["f"]; doesn't generate warning. Have you reported this to WRI?

@xzczd May I ask where to report to WRI?

In the top menu, Help -> Give feedback, or directly visit https://www.wolfram.com/support/contact/?topic=feedback They will reply in time :) .

@xzczd thx. I have reported to WRI.

After discussing with Wolfram Technical Support, I agree that this way of using Interpretation is unsafe.
Format[x[i_]]:=
    Interpretation[Subscript[x,i],x[i]];

Some cases I found:

ToString[x[1]] will cause infinite recursion;
evaluating x[1] in the terminal will cause infinite recursion, although in the notebook will not.

A solution provided by Wolfram Technical Support is to use ToExpression/ToString:
Format[x[i_]]:=
    Interpretation[Subscript[x,i],ToExpression["x["<>ToString[i]<>"]"]];

Notice that if using this method, ToString[x[1],InputForm] will give the desired "x[1]".
Besides this "meta" method, one can use MakeBoxes instead:
x/:MakeBoxes[x[i_],_]:=
    With[{box=SubscriptBox["x",MakeBoxes[i]]},
        InterpretationBox[box,x[i]]
    ];

which is a bit inconvenient but safe.
